# MongoDB collection Ling query when query is built against base class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to query a IMongoCollection using Linq. I have a IMongoCollection and I get a IMongoQueryable when calling AsQueryable on the collection. However I am then trying to append a where clause using an Expression<Func<BaseEntity, bool>> as the predicate. This is resulting in an exception. MongoEntity inherits BaseEntity, adn the expression is passed to the method as a parameter. I'd like to find a solution that doesnt require exposing MongoEntity to the calling code.

Trying to keep dependencies on specific database implementations out of my application code. To that end I have a base repository interface that is used:

```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null);
    }
```

The application uses base entity classes. These are then inherited in the data access layer with database specific version which add functionality specific to that particular database. As an example:

```
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MongoEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        // Database specific properties and methods
    }
```

I then have an implementation of the repository interface for each database type. For MongoDB:

```
    public class Repository<TEntity, TBaseEntity> : IRepository<TBaseEntity> where TEntity : class, TBaseEntity where TBaseEntity : class
    {
        protected IMongoCollection<TEntity> Collection
        {
            get;
        }

        protected Repository2(DataContext context)
        {
            Collection = context.RetriveCollection<TEntity>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TBaseEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TBaseEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TBaseEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TBaseEntity>> orderBy = null)
        {
            return BuildQuery(filter, orderBy).ToList();
        }

        private IQueryable<TBaseEntity> BuildQuery(Expression<Func<TBaseEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TBaseEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TBaseEntity>> orderBy = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TBaseEntity> query = Collection.AsQueryable();
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }
            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
```

An example of how this would be called in the client application:
 `repository.Get(x => x.Name == "A");`

I’ve had this working well with entity framework using MySQL as the back end, however trying to implement it with the MongoDB C# driver (no entity framework) I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=ValueType 'MongoEntity' of parameterSerializer does not match parameter type 'BaseEntity'. Arg_ParamName_Name
  Source=MongoDB.Driver
  StackTrace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToFilterTranslators.ExpressionToFilterTranslator.TranslateLambda(TranslationContext context, LambdaExpression lambdaExpression, IBsonSerializer parameterSerializer, Boolean asRoot)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToPipelineTranslators.WhereMethodToPipelineTranslator.Translate(TranslationContext context, MethodCallExpression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.Translators.ExpressionToExecutableQueryTranslators.ExpressionToExecutableQueryTranslator.Translate[TDocument,TOutput](MongoQueryProvider`1 provider, Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.MongoQuery`2.Execute()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq3Implementation.MongoQuery`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I understand this would be because the query is being built using BaseEntity, whereas the MongoCollection being queried is of type MongoEntity. Is there a way to convert the query to MongoEntity within the Get method of the repository, or another way of doing this that doesn’t expose the MongoEntity to the client code?